Imperative Apex in LWCs seems to wait for other Imperative methods to return in Production orgs
I have a LWC with two child LWCs in it. Each child LWC has an imperatively-called method to grab data, however, one of the children's methods takes, on average, a few seconds longer since it calls a more demanding Apex method.
imperativeMethod(parameters)
    .then(data => {
        this.data = data
    }).catch(error => {
        this.error = error;
    }).finally(() => {this.isLoading = false;})

When the method completes, the loading spinners go away, and data is shown in a lightning-data table. These two methods, one in each child, are both called simultaneously every time the parameters passed in from the parent change.
In scratch orgs, everything seems to work as expected. The parent parameters change, both tables show spinners, the first child table loads in less than a second, and the second child table loads in about 5 seconds.
In production orgs after deploying the 2GP package, the first time the parameters are passed in, the first child table loads in less than a second, and the second child table loads in about 5 seconds, as expected. However, when the parameters are changed again, BOTH tables take 5 seconds (or longer) to load, and always appear at exactly the same time, with no variation at all. Additionally, the spinners often freeze (stop spinning) for 2-3 seconds before both tables load. It is as if the faster child is waiting for the slower child, and then isLoading is set to false on each table simultaneously.
Things I have tried

I'm not quite sure where to start because I can't recreate it in a scratch org.

Tried different browsers, occurs in both safari and chrome

Changed session settings in production to match scratch
a. changed locker api version from 49 to 61
b. turned on "Enable secure and persistent browser caching to improve performance"
c. turned on "Use Lightning Web Security for Lightning web components and Aura components"
d. turned on "Enable Stricter Content Security Policy"


Any ideas? Thanks!

You might have come across an effect usually termed "boxcarring", e.g. see here. Apart from your LWC with its child components, - are the pages identical between scratch orgs and prod?

Thanks Felix, I think you are right. Both pages are identical, so still not sure why it only happens in production. But when this parent parameter is refreshed, I've noticed that even methods on inactive but visited lightning-tabs are being run, which brings the total methods called well over 5, maybe enabling boxcarring. I'm going to try to prevent methods from being called on inactive tabs to see if it fixes it.

Spent the past few hours on it. I reduced the number of apex calls made during the parent parameter update down from 21 to 9, which improved the response time of the slower child from ~5.5 seconds to ~2.5 seconds, but the faster child still waits for it (only in production). I wonder if boxcarring only happens in certain instances? Like not in scratch orgs, or it changes based on session settings... I'll keep looking into it. Thanks for leading me down the right track @FelixvanHove!

No problem. If you find a useful solution, post it as answer to your own question  - you can, and it might help others as well!

This is almost certainly boxcarring. Take a look at my answer to this and take note of the recommended orchestration approach. We eventually created a separate headless LWC that handles queuing calls to the server in such a way that up to 5 calls run in parallel but further ones are held back until one of the active calls has finished. This solves the problem for us.

BTW this happens on all types of org. I am guessing you run scratch orgs with LWC debugging enabled and that this turns off boxcarring...?

@PhilW, sorry for the late reply. Thanks for the help, that answer you linked is helpful. I am going to try implementing a queue using orchestration instead of setTimeout, as you mentioned. I also never thought about using this technique not only to prevent boxcarring, but also to split up a CPU-intensive call into multiple, smaller, parallel calls that will then go faster and avoid the 10 second limit. I might use that to speed up this one slow ~2.5 second call (which is the slowest call in the boxcar) if I can find a way to break it into parallel chunks.

In regard to why it's only happening in production, I am still unsure. LWC debugging was not enabled in my scratch org. I just spent a few hours looking through the open source LWC code hoping to find something about boxcar'ing there. There is a lot of conditionals like (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'), but I couldn't find anything that related these conditionals to enqueueing or boxcar'ing (I actually couldn't find anything about enqueuing or boxcar'ing in the LWC repo at all... maybe I'm looking in the wrong place. I spent most of my time in "lwc/packages/@lwc").

Try turning LWC debug off on your scratch org and see if that changes the behaviour.

No change unfortunately.
